# Is it possible to create one-time addresses, like in monero?

Tags: cryptography

In http://src.getmonero.org/library/Zero-to-Monero-1-0-0.pdf, chapter "5.2 One-time addresses", there is description of how to create them.

The problem is that Monero uses Ed25519 and Ethereum secp256k1.

Is it possible to apply the same mathematical operations to a different curve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction presented in that paper only assumes that the discrete log and decisional Diffie Hellman problems are hard, which is certainly thought to be true for secp256k1.

So yes, in that sense secp256k1 works just as well as Ed25519. On the other hand, the model of view/spend keys doesn't make sense natively in Ethereum, since everyone can see when the tokens are spent, so this scheme is no better (and far less efficient) than using an HD wallet.